# spring boot oauth & facebook reference

Tags: angularjs, facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, yaml

I'm starting to play around with OAUTH2 in spring boot. I'm currently trying to edit the simple example on this website: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

But I would like to display more of the person who logs in like email, age and stuff that can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Could you guys give me any advice to get any of the information that's described in the url above?

This part is used as login:

```
<div class="container" ng-show="!home.authenticated">
    With Facebook: <a href="/login">click here</a>
</div>
```

Then there is this part in the angular code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular
            .module("app", [])
            .config(
                    function($httpProvider) {
                        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
                    }).controller("home", function($http, $location) {
                var self = this;
                $http.get("/user").success(function(data) {
                    self.user = data.userAuthentication.details.name;
                    // i added the following line self.details =
                    self.details = data.userAuthentication.details
                    self.authenticated = true;
                                    $http.get("")
                }).error(function() {
                    self.user = "N/A";
                    self.authenticated = false;
                });
                self.logout = function() {
                    $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                        self.authenticated = false;
                        $location.path("/");
                    }).error(function(data) {
                        console.log("Logout failed")
                        self.authenticated = false;
                    });
                };
            });
</script>
```

Then I put home.details on the screen and it shows this:{"name":"firstname lastname","id":"some-numbers"}

I think /user refers to a method in the socialapplication.java. So I'm wondering where do I edit what information get's retrieved from facebook.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    // @formatter:on
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setOrder(-100);
    return registration;
}

private Filter ssoFilter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            "/login/facebook");
    OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
    facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(),
            facebook().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    facebookFilter.setTokenServices(
            new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId()));
    return facebookFilter;
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client")
public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails facebook() {
    return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("facebook.resource")
public ResourceServerProperties facebookResource() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
}
```

Here is the YAML file.

```
    facebook:
      client:
        clientId: xxxxxxxxxx
        clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
        tokenName: oauth_token
        authenticationScheme: query
        clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      resource:
        userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me

    logging:
      level:
        org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

I'm really at a loss here and hope someone can help me to retrieve more information from facebook.

Thanks for any kind of help!